# When using chart.js, custom tooltips disappear immediately after rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm using chart js 2 to display several Line graphs. I want to set a custom tooltip to allow me to view additional data when the user hovers over a point on the graph. However, every time I add a callback function (no matter what the function returns), it causes the tooltip to disappear. It properly renders my custom text for a brief moment, but then it disappears. I have to move my mouse around constantly to be able to read the tooltips. Here's the documentation on this function https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback

I've tried changing virtually every chart option I can. I'm currently using the callback function 'label', but I've tried beforeLabel and afterLabel as well. One thing that I noticed had an effect is when I changed the value of "animation: { duration } ". It's currently set to 0 because I don't want any of the other animations when the charts change, because they update frequently. I set it to 1000 and I noticed that the tooltip persisted for slightly longer and had a darker background, but the overall chart rendering seemed to slow down. I've also changed the callback function's format from an arrow function to a regular function.

Here are my chart options, with the relevant portion spaced out more towards the end:

```js
const chartOptions = {
        legend: {
          labels: {
            fontColor: NUMBER_COLOR,
            fontSize: 12
          }
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: "Frame",
              fontColor: SCALE_LABEL_COLOR,
              fontSize: 14
            },
            stepSize: ystep,
            ticks: {
              min: XMIN,
              max: XMAX,
              stepSize: (XMAX - XMIN) / TICK_NUMS,
              maxRotation: 0,
              minRotation: 0,
              fontColor: NUMBER_COLOR,
              fontSize: 12
            },
            type: "linear"
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: this.props.yAxisUnits,
              fontColor: SCALE_LABEL_COLOR,
              fontSize: 14
            },
            ticks: {
              id: "0",
              min: yChartMin,
              max: yChartMax,
              stepSize: Number(((yChartMax - yChartMin) / TICK_NUMS).toFixed(DECIMAL_NUM)),
              maxRotation: 0,
              minRotation: 0,
              display: true,
              fontColor: NUMBER_COLOR,
              fontSize: 13
            }
          }]
        },


        animation: {
          duration: 0
        },
        tooltips: {
          intersect: true,
          mode: "nearest",
          enabled: true,
          callbacks: {
            label: (tooltipItems, data) => {
              const labelText = [
                data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label + ": " + data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItems.index].y,
                "Time: " + data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItems.index].time
              ];
              return labelText;
            }
          }
        }
      };
```

The data points themselves each follow the format:

```js
{
    x: xValue,
    y: yValue,
    time: timeValue
}
```

and my chart is displayed via:

```
<Line
  data={chartData}
  options={chartOptions}
  width={DEFAULT_WIDTH}
  height={DEFAULT_HEIGHT}
  getElementAtEvent={(e: any) => this.clickedElement(e)}
/>
```

When I delete the callback function "label", the tooltip persists and displays as expected. Please let me know if you can offer help in any way.

Thanks!